# How to get l.control layers or copyright into panel / div

Tags: leaflet, panel, layer-control

I am tring to get l.controls like layers, copyright or draw into panel/div like:

```
<div class="panel">
 <div id="layers">...HERE LAYERS...</div>
 <div id="copyright">...HERE COPYRIGHTS...</div>
</div>
```

So my question is, how to define new position or function that will get layers into panel/div?

Comment: See [Leaflet - put controls outside the div map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041651/leaflet-put-controls-outside-the-div-map)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to get your point, but:

In leaflet, the map view (where layers are) is set by this javascript instruction:

> var mymap = L.map('divmap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

where `divmap` is the id of the div where there is the map view. So you can put this `<div id='divmap'></div>` wherever you want in your page.

For the copyright (or attribution), you can set a different position than the default one using the setPosition method (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#control), e.g., to put it in the top right corner of the map:

> mymap.attributionControl.setPosition('topright')

or try to set an absolute position by overriding the CSS class 'leaflet-control-attribution' (not tested).

Ju

Comment: I want to get L.controls (f.e. L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);) not into corners (positions topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright), but into my element div (f.e. <div id="layers"></div>)... I dont want to use default positions, I want to define new positions - but I dont know how - or somehow get L.control into my elements